# How Timeboxes align with sprints in hybrid approach

Tags: dsdm

How do Timeboxes align with sprints in a hybrid approach like dsdm atern and scrum

Comment: can you provide further detail on the problem you are trying to solve? This will allow the community to direct answers.

Comment: I think you need to describe, or link to, the "hybrid approach" of which you're thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too am not entirely sure what you mean by the hybrid approach, but a timebox is essentially a sprint - a dedicated slot of time to do a certain amount of work.

If you're following the DSDM method, the manual suggests breaking the project down into a number of iterative cycles, with each cycle subdivided into timeboxes/sprints.

For me, one of the major differences between DSDM and Scrum is that DSDM works on the basis of a fixed deadline for delivery, whereas scrum doesn't necessarily specify this.